# How could Thanos please the Mistress Death by killing half of the lives in universe?

Tags: marvel, thanos

Why would Thanos' killing half of the life in the universe please Mistress Death?

I mean, all men are doomed to die when their lifetime comes to an end. Mistress Death could just wait and watch; the lifespan of mortal men should be only a moment to her. So why did Thanos go to such a length to gather the Infinity Stones and kill half of the life in the universe?

If Mistress Death really wanted more death, shouldn't the right thing to do be creating more lives (raising fertility)? After all, only the living can die.

Comment: Why do people like roses as gifts? They just wither, but they do that naturally on the vine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This was explained early on in the story.  It was stated there were more people alive than ever died and Mistress Death considered that a ‘cosmic imbalance’.  She chose Thanos to fix this.  He learned of the Infinity Gems and decided they were the tool to use, and used them in a way he thought would please her.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**Infinity Gauntlet #1**](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_Gauntlet_Vol_1_1)</sup></sub>

Comment: Great answer! You could add a snippet from the comics (the Issue #, the story arc etc.) where this is mentioned to support your answer.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the appropriate panel from Infinity Gauntlet #1.

Comment: Should note that at least on Earth, this statistic is utterly untrue.  Current estimates are around 102 billion humans have ever been born, but only around 7-8 billion are currently alive, to say nothing of all the other species on life on the planet.  Maybe we're the outlier and it's the other way around on all the other planets?  Though given most of the heroes in the Infinity War saga come from Earth, we're an outlier in more than one way...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman We're an outlier. Exponential growth (remember, 2 million years to reach 1 billion, another 200 years to reach 7 billion) means that, given additional planets to support the population, we could probably crash though 100 billion in a short amount of time.

Comment: @chepner That would assume immortality, or something like it. Otherwise, the the growth vs death rate would still mean far more dead than currently alive.

Comment: @Harabeck Not really. As long as you live long enough to see your grandchildren born, the currently-alive can rapidly gain ground on the ever-alive.

Comment: @chepner In that case, the question arises what mistress Death stands to gain from killing many people arbitrarily, as the "imbalance" would quickly return. Killing half of the bacteria in a colony doesn't do much if each of them multiplies in less than an hour. Sure, killing that many people probably affects the growth rate dramatically if it triggers civilizational collapses or even a mass extinctions, but that's quite a long shot and it seems less complicated to do so directly. The half-death hammer may be the only tool in Death's toolbox, but I don't think her problem is a nail.

Comment: "There are more people alive now then ever died" was a common phrase back then (1991, when it was written). The Population Explosion was a big deal at the time. Anyone reading the comic would have known Death was simply repeating the nightly news.

Comment: @OwenReynolds "More people are alive now than have ever lived" was a [lying pile](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0d76/78447627bc6a8fc0a06bf4cb6223857442f3.pdf) [of Malthusian](http://theanarchistlibrary.org/library/murray-bookchin-the-population-myth.pdf) [propaganda](http://dwardmac.pitzer.edu/Anarchist_Archives/bookchin/gp/perspectives15.html) even in the early 90s.

Comment: @Lexible Maybe, but it made the news and was taken seriously. China went to their brutal 1-child policy in 1979, 12 years before the comic. And Death saying "I know that's not true, but it offends me people would even say it" doesn't have the same ring.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Earth isn't supposed to be an outlier, Thanos actually makes this claim about Earth specifically too. Silver Surfer #35, page 6. Then he goes on to say that "this condition is not unique to earth" on page 14. So, yeah.